# log4j custom appender stop method not getting called

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to implement a custom log appender for log4j and will need to initialize some resources before start and cleanup at the end. Somehow my stop method will not be executed.
I've tried using  `LogManager.shutdown();` but I cannot see my method getting called.

This is my appender class:

```
@Plugin(name = "CELogAppender", category = Core.CATEGORY_NAME, elementType = Appender.ELEMENT_TYPE)
public class CELogAppender extends AbstractAppender {
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, LogEvent> eventMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    protected CELogAppender(String name, Filter filter, Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
                            boolean ignoreExceptions, Property[] properties) {
        super(name, filter, layout, ignoreExceptions, properties);
        System.out.println("new celogappender");
    }

    public static CELogAppender createAppender(@PluginAttribute("name") String name,
                                               @PluginAttribute("Filter") Filter filter,
                                               @PluginAttribute("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout) {
        return new CELogAppender(name, filter, layout, false, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void append(LogEvent event) {
        eventMap.put(Instant.now().toString(), event);
        System.out.println("event added");
    }

    public ConcurrentMap<String, LogEvent> getEvents() {
        return eventMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.out.println("start appender");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        System.out.println("stop appender");
    }
}
```

And this is a simple test

```
public class CELogAppenderTests {
    private static Logger logger;
    private static CELogAppender ceLogAppender;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup() {
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(CELogAppenderTests.class.getName());
        LoggerContext loggerContext = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
        Configuration config = loggerContext.getConfiguration();
        PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
                .withPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n")
                .build();
        ceLogAppender = CELogAppender.createAppender("CELogAppender", null, layout);
        ceLogAppender.start();
        config.addAppender(ceLogAppender);


        AppenderRef appenderRef = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("CELogAppender", null, null);
        AppenderRef[] appenderRefs = new AppenderRef[]{appenderRef};
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger(false, Level.ALL,
                CELogAppenderTests.class.getName(), "true", appenderRefs, null, config, null);

        loggerConfig.addAppender(ceLogAppender, null, null);
        config.addLogger(CELogAppenderTests.class.getName(), loggerConfig);
        loggerContext.updateLoggers();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAppenderNotEmpty() {
        logger.info("A message");
        assertFalse(ceLogAppender.getEvents().isEmpty());
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void shutdown() {
        System.out.println("shutdown");
        LogManager.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I can see the console output

```
new celogappender
start appender
event added
shutdown
```

but I am missing the output from my stop method:

```
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        System.out.println("stop appender");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution, I had to use/override the stop method like this

```
@Override
public boolean stop(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {

}
```

Comment: The above stop method is defined in LifeCycle2 interface which is implemented by AbstractAppender (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LifeCycle2.html#stop-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). AbstractAppender also implements LifeCycle interface that implements stop() overriding this does not work. The documentation does not explain the reason.